# Get interface builder view dimensions programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, tvos

I have a UITableView with two different sized row/cell heights. I have the two different layouts all set up in Interface Builder and everything is working fine. What I don't like is that to make this work I have to override various sizing methods like UITableView:heightForRowAt and hard-code the same heights that I've already defined in IB. So my question is, is there a way to just read the view dimensions from my laid out views in IB so I don't need to duplicate and possibly introduce undesired consequences down the road?

Comment: If you're using constraints to define the cell heights, you can simply let auto-layout handle it. You shouldn't need `heightForRowAt` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up getting it working this way. It would still be nice to know if this is possible, however.